# Integrating Amazon Connect Stream API and Lambda API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-connect

I am using Amazon Connect Stream APIs for customized Agent control panel with Amazon Connect.
https://github.com/aws/amazon-connect-streams

Now I want to integrate lambda API gateway in customized agent screen to save page data into database. I am thinking to use Amazon Cognito feature for authentication of lambda request call.

I can directly call lambda API from my page but to provide authentication security, is there any connect stream API directly available which can use connect login credentials for authentication so that I can avoid creating separate user pool in Amazon Cognito?

Thanks in advance,
Gan

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there is no way to use the Amazon Connect user identity (login credentials) to secure the API, as they are not accessible via the streams API.

I would recommend using a pre-shared API key to protect the api functions in API gateway. Although this does provider identification of the calling user, it is better then an unprotected API endpoint.

The only other alternative to this would be forcing the user to login twice, once for the page loading the stream API (this would give you a user-specific token via cognitio, that could be used as the API gateway authorizer) and then a second time when the streams API code was loaded, which would be the Amazon Connect agent authentication.